# JTree data not loading from the database (MySQL)

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtree

I am creating the category table on MySQL database. I need to list all categories need to view on `JTree` but it is not loading. Code which tried so far I wrote below.

**Category table**

```
+------------+
|id | catname|
+------------+
|1  | book   |
|2  | drink  |
|3  | cake   |
+------------+
```

```java
public void LoadtTree()
{
   try {
        pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from category");
        rs = pst.executeQuery();     
        DefaultMutableTreeNode categories = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Categories");
        String currentGroup = null;
        while (rs.next()) {
               String group = rs.getString("catname");
               DefaultMutableTreeNode categorynames= new DefaultMutableTreeNode(rs.getString("catname"));
               categories.add(categorynames);         
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){ex.getMessage();}
}
```

When the form is loaded it displays the default nodes only. How can I load the database values to this node?

[image: IMG]

**Connection**

```
 Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    ResultSet rs;


   public void Connect()
{

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/emk", "root","");                     
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(fo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(fo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you posted seems to be ok to me, but it seems that the `DefaultMutableTreeNode categories` is never added to the user-interface. Can you post the complete controller class code? Or debug trough the method `LoadTree()` and check whether the categories from the database are added.

Comment: can you write the code sir. this is not mvc sir. just core java

Comment: 1) Change `}catch(Exception ex){ex.getMessage();}` to `}catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}`. It will help solve problems. If not now, then in the future. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use DefaultMutableTreeNode.

It is't my code, but try to look at this example : http://www.javaknowledge.info/populate-jtree-from-mysql-database/

Comment: sir if you write the full code it is easy to understand sir pls

Comment: *"if you write the full code"* SO is not a code generation machine.